# Cant use safemysql to insert or select DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am using [Ionutvmi's](https://github.com/ionutvmi/master-login-system) login system, and his way of inserting to DB is [colshrapnel's](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) mysql library "safemysql". It seems very good but I cannot insert or select. I have tried with using some examples and also using some of Ionutvmi's code for inserting, but it don't work.

This works (not my code):

```
if($db->getRow("SELECT `userid` FROM `".MLS_PREFIX."users` 
WHERE `email` = ?s", "someuser@gmail.com"))
echo  "Email already in use !";
```

This doesn't work:

```
  $user_data = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'headline' => $headline,
  'category' => $category,
  'telephone' => $telephone,
  'email' => $email,
  'token' => $token,
  'price' => $price,
  );

if(($db->query("INSERT INTO `".MLS_PREFIX."ad` SET ?u", $user_data)) ) {
    $page->success = 1;
} else
    $page->error = "There was an error with db ! Please try again !";
}
```

It always display $page->error.

I want to know how I can use the placeholders in "safemysql" In order to INSERT and SELECT and echo out from my database?

It is also very difficult to know what errors I get since this don't work with the query.

```
echo mysqli_errno($db->error) . ": " . mysqli_error($db->error). "\n";
```

Ps: Everything I use is created by "safemysql" and I include init.php from [master-login-system](https://github.com/ionutvmi/master-login-system) that uses "safemysql"

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, make sure you're not mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: You're also using two different DB connection variables `$db` and `$link`

Comment: `$db` is the right database, `$link` is only example code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php.

Comment: Did you add error reporting and if so, did it throw any back?

Comment: @fred-ii This dont work
`echo mysql_errno($db->error) . ": " . mysql_error($db->error). "\n";`
only error report is `Undefined property: SafeMySQL::$error`
and
`mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`

Comment: My guess is that your DB connection is `mysqli_`, am I right? It's hard to diagnose with what you posted, but I'm willing to bet my bottom dollar on it. Resource is DB connection ;)

Comment: There's the cause then. `mysqli_` and `mysql_` do not mix together. Either make everything `mysql_` or everything `mysqli_`.

Comment: The only time i actually specify mysql or mysqli is in the echo statement. Everything else is covered by "safemysql" and I include init.php from master-login-system. Thus the connecting part is also covered by another file created by https://github.com/ionutvmi/master-login-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should state that the answer is **forgetting to *start* the enclosed brackets after *else***.

To further answer my question for other readers that want to use safemysql or bootstrap-login-system.

This is how you can INSERT to database. I am taking the liberty of assuming that the database already contain the table with the respected array keys as key in database.

**How to insert to database:**

(0) Connect to database:

This can be done in several ways. I used master-login-system and changed [settings.php](https://github.com/ionutvmi/master-login-system/blob/master/inc/settings.php).

```
// database details
$set->db_host = 'localhost'; // database host
$set->db_user = 'root'; // database user
$set->db_pass = ''; // database password
$set->db_name = 'mls'; // database name
define('MLS_PREFIX', 'mls_');
```

Then i included [init.php](https://github.com/ionutvmi/master-login-system/blob/master/inc/init.php) to my file.

```
<?php
include "init.php";
```

(1) Create your array:

```
$user_data = array(
'name' => $name,
'headline' => $headline,
'category' => $category,
'telephone' => $telephone,
'email' => $email,
'token' => $token,
'price' => $price,
);
```

(2) Insert to db.

```
if ($db->query("INSERT INTO `table` SET ?u", $user_data)){
  echo "success!";
} else {
  echo "error, could not insert to db!";
}
```

**How to SELECT from database**:

(0) [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) has a guide. Though I could not understand it all at first this is how to SELECT:

```
$name = $db->getOne('SELECT email FROM mls_ad WHERE name = ?s','Doloris Patsburgh');
echo $name->scalar;
```

To get data these are the most used helper functions. But read the docs from [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):
query, getOne, getRow, getCol, getAll, getInd, getIndCol